# FastAPI не загружает страницу

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

Начал изучать FastAPI (https://fastapi.netlify.app/ru/tutorial/first-steps/)
Запустил, все заработало, но после перезапуска `uvicorn` сайт перестал грузиться.
Я перезапустил `uvicorn` но это не помогло. Просто висит бесконечная загрузка с черным экраном, причем в первый раз все работало.

Код:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Запускаю: `uvicorn main:app --reload`

Лог:

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['\путь\к\сайту']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [2664] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [3372]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Перехожу на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` и вижу пустой экран который не загружается.
В чем проблема?

Comment: Возможно это глюк какой-то, попробуйте комп перезагрузить.

Comment: Странно, но это помогло.

Comment: Это не странно. Это первое, что нужно попробовать при любом подобном глюке. Возможно или предыдущий запущенный процесс uvicorn завис, или что-то подобное. Можно попытаться через диспетчер задач лишние процессы прибить, или просто перезагрузиться.